# polymer paper-element IE disable state

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm currently stuck with the paper-input element.

I explain, using Internet Explorer Edge, the label and the value of my paper-input elements in disable state are overlayed.
I have to enable the paper-input, edit, then the label is moving on the top of the paper-input.

Does someone fixed it ?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually set the "always-float-label" attribute as a workaround whenever I run into such issues. This way the title also floats when the value is empty, but at least there are no overlays ;)

**HTML-Code for quick & easy approach with small design impact** :

```
<paper-input always-float-label disabled label="Label"></paper-input>
```

If you want to only use this workaround when an item is disabled, you can probably bind the disabled-attribute to the same property as the "always-float-label" :

**HTML-Code for approach with smaller design impact** :

```
<paper-input always-float-label="{{disabled}}" disabled="{{disabled}}" label="Label"></paper-input>
```

Properties of the nesting Polymer-element :

```
disabled: {type:Boolean, value:true}
```

If you want to use even more code and make it working like it is intended, you could make the always-float-label calculated based on the value :

**HTML-Code for approach without any design impact**  :

```
<paper-input always-float-label="{{_alwaysFloat(val)}}" disabled label="Label" value="{{val}}"></paper-input>
```

Javascript :

```
Polymer({
             is: "your-element",
             properties: {
                 val:{type:String}
             },
             _alwaysFloat:function(val) {
                 return val=="";
             }
});
```